# ExcelDNA and Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, excel-dna

I'm new to C#, creating excel plugins and also new to ExcelDNA. I got the examples working on http://exceldna.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started. The UDF "MultiplyThem" works as expected.

When I modify example #3 on that site to grab data from a mysql database. I reference not only ExcelDna.Integration.dll but also MySql.Data.dll in my project. I then compile it with this statement:

```
c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe /target:library /reference:ExcelDna.Integration.dll /reference:MySql.Data.dll TestLib.cs
```

When I open up the excel-add in and start typing in my UDF(in this case, "=MultiplyThem()") there is no UDF called "MultiplyThem". Why did it suddenly stop working? Here's my C# code:

```
using ExcelDna.Integration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

public class MyFunctions
{
[ExcelFunction(Description = "Grabs data from database", Category = "Useful functions")]
public static string MultiplyThem(string[] args)
{
    string connString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=test;Uid=root;password=pword";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
    MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT field_value FROM customers";
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    string myvariable = "bad";

    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        myvariable = reader["field_value"].ToString();
    }

    return myvariable;
}
}
```

And my Test1.dna file (I am targeting .NET Framework 4 in my project):

```
<DnaLibrary RuntimeVersion="v4.0">
   <ExternalLibrary Path="TestLib.dll"/>
</DnaLibrary>
```

Comment: Have you tried dropping the MySql.Data.MySqlClient dll in the folder where you have your dll? That should help make sure whether locating that dependency is the source of the issue.

Comment: Did you mean MySql.Data.dll? (I couldn't find a MySql.Data.MySqlClient.dll file anywhere). I've got the MySql.Data.dll in my folder and referencing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel-DNA does not currently support string arrays as parameters. If you change the string[] args to object[] args it should be fine.

Comment: You would typically want to cache the connection, and probably a prepared SqlCommand with parameters, in static variables. Each function call would check whether they have already been set up, and if possible just re-bind the parameters and execute using the existing connection and command.

Comment: For connection caching there's a ThreadPool in .Net. No need to care about this, but you can configure it via connection string params.